# Why memory studies was a strong area of research during 90's?

Tags: social-psychology, memory, neuroimaging, history-of-psychology

Memory studies seemed to have flourished during nineties - particularly early nineties.
Not only in Psychology, but in neuroscience, in social sciences, in History, there was a period in which a lot of papers and books related to memory where published.
I am interested in the factors that made this area particularly important as an emerging interdisciplinar field of research.
Is it still a popular subject of research nowadays?

Comment: I wonder if this would be better on https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ ? From my perspective in neuroscience, memory is just as popular now as a subject of study as it's ever been so I'm not sure what exactly is contributing to your experience of the early 90s being particularly special.

Comment: This a good suggestion as I am taking as a premise the fact that social, economical and technological contributions influence subjects of study. Nevertheless I believe people who know cognitive sciences or neuroscience might have clues - where any major tecnological advances in early nineties? I am aware of "second cognitive revolution" and narrative as a paradigm, which I believe where influential. But I am not sure. Regardless, interdisclinary dialogues can show new pathways of research.

Comment: I tried to add new tags which might be helpful

Comment: I suggest you incorporate these intuitions, and uncertainty about them, ideally referenced, in the question. It would make it better founded, and maybe make clear why you prefer an answer here as opposed to hsm.

Comment: Hsm might be better - i don't have more than intuitions or hypotheses at this moment.